# Why does System.getProperty("user.dir") not returning the expected value

Tags: java, selenium

When I tried the below code, it is not returning the current directory. Instead it is returning only **`.`** i.e. a **dot**.

```
String current = System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.out.println("Current working directory in Java : " + current);
```

Output:

```
Current working directory in Java :.
```

Comment: `.` is the current directory.

Comment: i get the full path of the working dir instead of just a dot

Answer (score 0):

Whereever the value is coming from seems to be **platform-specific** but certainly **`.`** i.e. `"dot"` is not a particularly useful result. Not sure how it was processed but if your main aim is to get a meaningful value, you can use either of the following options as per [this documentation](https://coderanch.com/t/609125/java/System-getProperty-user-dir-fetching):

- `getCanonicalPath()`
- `getCanonicalFile()`
- `getAbsolutePath()`
- `getAbsoluteFile()`

A *Windows OS* based example:

- Ideal scenario:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    System.out.println("user.dir: "+System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    user.dir: C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\learn-automation
    ```
- Alternative:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    String user_dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    File pwdDir = new File(user_dir);
    System.out.println("Current working directory in Java : " + pwdDir.getCanonicalPath());
    System.out.println("Current working directory in Java : " + pwdDir.getCanonicalFile());
    System.out.println("Current working directory in Java : " + pwdDir.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("Current working directory in Java : " + pwdDir.getAbsoluteFile());
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    Current working directory in Java : C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\learn-automation
    Current working directory in Java : C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\learn-automation
    Current working directory in Java : C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\learn-automation
    Current working directory in Java : C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\learn-automation
    ```